# intellij idea build error reading 3rd party jar

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to rebuild an "idea" project that built without problem about a year ago, but now I see this error:

```
Error:java: error reading /home/oreilly/neptus-mbari/lib/xj3d/xj3d-all.jar; java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 41: file:/home/oreilly/neptus-mbari/lib/xj3d/\
```

What exactly causes this error? The message says error reading the third-party xj3d-all.jar file, but how is it getting a local url from that jar file? I'm running idea community edition 2018.1.8 on ubuntu 18.04.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see this library in project dependencies ("Project Structure | Module | Dependencies")?

Comment: Thanks @y.bedrov - this problem has disappeared since I upgraded idea to the 2020 community edition.